# open document in browser without generating file in server side

Tags: google-app-engine

I have stored user document (ms word) in data store as blob object.
How do I open this in a browser? I can make it downloadable but I want user to view the document in browser before downloading it. how do I do that?

I think,   to be able to open the file in browser by setting response headers (inline and content-type), the file should physically exist on a file location.
I don't have space to generate the file and then write to the browser. How do  I handle it?

can I store them in google drive? does reading and uploading will be charged? any pointer to examples?

```
    daoIntf=new DAOImpl();
    document = daoIntf.getEntity("Document", id);
    Blob docBlob=(Blob)document.getProperty("resume");
    String fileName=(String)document.getProperty("fileName");
    String contentType=(String)document.getProperty("contentType");
    response.setContentType(contentType);   
    response.setHeader("Pragma" , "no-cache");   
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control" , "no-cache");   
    response.setDateHeader("Expires" , 0);       
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition" , "inline;filename=\""+fileName+"\"");   
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(docBlob.getBytes());
```

-thanks
  Ma

Answer (score 0):

If you have a document in the Blobstore, you simply need to provide a link to it (i.e. `.getServingUrl()` in Java). When a user clicks on that link, his browser will either offer to download it, or it will open it in the preview mode if this user has a plugin or extension that can do it.

Comment: that is not I want.The files are job seeker's resumes.Recruiter has to see first and then download because his download counts.

Comment: There is no difference between "seeing" and "downloading" a Word file. If you want to show a preview, you can create an HTML version of the document for the preview purposes.

Comment: Agreed. how can I create html version of word doc out of byte array ?

Comment: You can use a tool to extract HTML from a Word document. There are different options available depending on which language you use.

Comment: I am thinking to upload the file to Google drive instead of storing as blob object and create a file export link and append to https://docs.google.com/viewer that will open the view in a viewer..

Answer (score 0):

There is an online Google Docs viewer that works on external documents: https://docs.google.com/a/iddiction.com/viewer?pli=1

Expose your documents [via servlet using `blobstoreService.serve(key, response)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Serving_a_blob) and then open them in the viewer.

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<url_of_your_document>&embedded=<true|false>
```

Comment: Tried the blobstoreService but It did not help as blobstoreService.serve(key, response) writes the bytes to outputstream of response object. To be able to use google doc viewer the file should be created and saved in some path before serving.

Comment: Above, `url_of_your_document` is the url of your servlet, where you serve the document. Also, do not use `Content-Disposition` as this forces browsers to download the file. Use just `Content-Type: application/msword`.